# Where can I change allocated memory of JDeveloper?

Tags: jdeveloper

Where can I change allocated memory of JDeveloper? Also Maximum and optimum memory for this IDE. My Machine has a 4GB RAM, I use SOA,BPEL frameworks in that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where can I change allocated memory of JDeveloper?

For JDeveloper 11.1.2.x, you can configure VM options in the JDeveloper configuration file at `jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev.conf`. For example, to set the maximum heap size to 2GB, add the following line to this file:

```
AddVMOption  -Xmx2048M
```

Note that this only affects the IDE - to set memory limits for the internal Weblogic Server, you can set the `USER_MEM_ARGS` environment variable before launching the IDE, like

```
$ export USER_MEM_ARGS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m"
```

> Also Maximum and optimum memory for this IDE

The more, the better. There is no limit besides those imposed by the operating system or the Java virtual machine you are using (32 bit vs. 64 bit).

> My Machine has a 4GB RAM, I use SOA,BPEL frameworks in that.

I **really** suggest that you add more memory. Use a 64 bit operating system and upgrade to at least 8 GB. You need to consider that it is not only the IDE which is consuming memory, but also the internal Weblogic Server,  where you are running your application during development. The internal WLS is launched as a separate java process and also consumes a considerable amount of memory.

Comment: As of now I am using a shared development server, I use Other programs thunderbird and firefox which takes ~1GB of RAM. Upgrading to 8GB isn't possible for me (Budget constraints in my project).